# How to extend pimcore object model and his resource class

Tags: model, resources, extend, pimcore

Basically I want to extend Pimcore\Object\Model\User with custom class named Website\Model\User.
In addition I want to extend the resource class of that model (Pimcore\Object\Model\User) and my new class Website\Model\User start using that new resource which extends the core's one.

What is the best way to achieve that in the system? Detailed instructions and explanations will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via the classmap.xml (in /website/var/config):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<zend-config xmlns:zf="http://framework.zend.com/xml/zend-config-xml/1.0/">
  <Pimcore\Object\Model\User>Website\Model\User</Pimcore\Object\Model\User>
  <Pimcore\Object\Model\User\Resource>Website\Model\User</Pimcore\Object\Model\User\Resource>
</zend-config>
```

(I'm not sure if this is the right notation for namespaced php).

Now you can create your custom classes

```
namespace Website\Model

class User extends Pimcore\Object\Model\User {
 ...
}
```

This is possible due to the Zend Class Autoloader.